I have a problem with ITM Data Trace on STM32F407
I have a non-comercial download of STM32Cube IDE. I want to use the ITM Data Trace on a  STM32F407 G disc1. In the main() call to initialise_monitor_handles(); the fun body in the system file is empty.  Is there anything that can be done about it or, a place to get a download of the function.
I have trace the code in the debugger and after it goes to that function it returns to main() without doing anything and goes to printf("Hello World\n"); but does not print and I have included <stdio.h>.  I also have selected Port 0 for the ITM Data console in the Microprocesor

Consider providing a [mre]. For that it is OK to assume that readers have the same hardware. Apaprt from that, try for [ask].
